# Motherboard of my printer that burns out

Tags: power-supply, motherboard

I'm asking for your help because I have some problems with electronics!
I am designing a 3D printer with LCD technology. For this printer I use a NanoDLP motherboard and a 24V 250W Tiger Power supply (links are at the end of the post). I have been facing problems for some time, the motherboard of my printer is burning out. I have replaced the NanoDLP board 3 times but it burns out randomly (one after 1 month, 1 after 1 week...).
I showed the board to a colleague who builds electronic boards and he assumes that the problem comes from the voltage limit of the capacitors and the regulator of the nanoDLP board versus the voltage delivered by the 24V supply:

- Maximum voltage of the regulator of the nanoDLP board: 26V
- Maximum voltage of the nanoDLP board input capacitors: 25V (assumed value)
- The exact voltage delivered by the 24V power supply is unknown. In general, power supplies are designed to operate with a guaranteed accuracy of 5% or 10%, regardless of the load.
  A tolerance of 5% gives a maximum of 25.2V, a voltage which is already too high for the input capacities. This implies a failure of the card.

To solve this problem, I see 3 solutions, but being a beginner in electronics, I would need your advice to know what is the right way:

- Buy a more accurate 24v 250W power supply. I started looking for one but I can't find one with an error of less than 5%, does it exist?
- Buy a voltage regulator that I would connect between the power supply and the motherboard, that would make sure that the voltage does not vary. However I can't find one
  for a power of 250W, I don't know if it exists either...
- Change the motherboard by another one better protected. I already have some ideas, including the MKS Gen L V2.1 card. But I would like to be sure that this card does not have the same
  problem as the other one. Does anyone know if it is more secure or if not what components I need to check to make sure it doesn't burn out?

If you have other ideas to solve my problem, I'm interested! I'm interested in any advice on electronics!

Thanks in advance !

Board NanoDLP : [fr.aliexpress.com]

Power supply Tiger Power: [www.tigerpower.com]

Board MKS Gen L v2.1 : [imprimante-3d-service.com]

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind.  First you may be purchasing a questionably designed/made motherboard.  Many of these "direct from china" products are counterfeit.  Second, you may be exceeding its design limits in some way and causing the problem.

Comment: How have you connected the devices together? Also, the links do not work. Do you have datasheets and manuals for the devices?

Comment: If you add a voltage regulator (preferably a switch-mode DC-DC converter) between the 24 V power supply and the motherboard, it only has to handle the power required by the motherboard, not the full power capability of the power supply.  I assume the power supply will also be providing 24 V to the heaters and motors.

Comment: _”25V (assumed value)”_ Bo markings on them?